# How to plot days on x-axis instead of hours with lubridate's duration object

Tags: r, ggplot2, lubridate

I have this data and I would like to plot the value against the time. The time column is a `duration` object from `lubridate`.

```
df = structure(list(value = c(0.146629368669261, -0.174585031699523, 
-0.0657191327768585, 0.206486326659542, 1.9076161363563, 0.319682206047181, 
0.00402265500880539, 0.125472536213693, 0.0868479511815217), 
    time = new("Duration", .Data = c(3600, 21600, 43200, 86400, 
    172800, 345600, 518400, 691200, 1382400))), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -9L))

df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = time, y=value)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_time()
```

[image]

How can I archive potentially with `scale_x_time()` that the x-axis shows not the hours in the format "Hours:Minutes:Seconds" but the number of days?

Comment: just scale it to days and use scale_continuous (?ddays: 1 duration day  = 86400 seconds). using duration you effectively transform your time variable into a continuous variable - it doesn't really make sense to transform it back to "actual" time (date or time class), so it would also be inappropriate to use scale_time here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the duration values are in seconds. Can´t you just rescale the x-ticks and labels accordingly (seconds to days)? Like this:

```
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = time, y=value)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,365*24*3600, 24*3600),
                     labels = 0:365, name = "time in days")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, and indeed this would be a workaround but I was hoping to find a solution with `scale_x_time()`

Comment: @MrNetherlands You could use `scale_x_time()` instead of `scale_x_continuous()` with the same parameters. This produces the same result. But I guess you want to use `scale_x_time` with some build in function for breaks and labels? Not sure I understand why...

Comment: Thanks, I was also thinking why I exactly I want to use scale_x_time however, there was no real reason so I happy to work with your proposed solution